# How to open tab in foreground when user presses Ctrl + Enter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a input DOM element that opens a tab when ctrl-enter is pressed. While I am able to get the tab to open, it always opens in the background (focus stays on the current tab) because ctrl is held down.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example: https://jsfiddle.net/b3a45uh1/

Pressing `ctrl + enter` in the textbox launches the tab in the background. Pressing `ctrl + shift + enter` in the textbox launches the tab in the foreground.

How can I have the tab launch in the foreground when the user presses exactly `ctrl + enter` without the extra `shift` key?

P.S. I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but things like `window.open(selectedBookmark.link).focus()` and manual initKeyboardEvent/initMouseEvent calls, both of which worked years before, no longer work.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have fine control over opening windows and tabs, they're controlled by the browser preferences.

Comment: To expand on Barmars comment: Why do you need a new tab, what is it that can't be done in the same tab, maybe in an overlay?

Comment: I'm creating a bookmark management app, so I do want to keep the app in the original tab while also opening a new tab with that bookmark's URL for the user.

Same tab would not allow the app to remain open. Overlay is a novel idea but doesn't seem to fit with the use case/user expectations.